# how to allow a Login permission can create database but cant drop database SQL

Tags: sql, database, authentication

a Login  windows  can create database  but can not drop that database
And  can create login but can not delete login

Please help me!!

Edit:
I'm using SQL Server 2005  on VMware

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which database are you using? Mysql? Postgresql?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 or SQL server 2008 , sorry, first time i ask question.. sr about this ,  pls help me!

Answer (score 0):

In login properties , in the securables node, `create any database` and `alter any database` is your goal.

Comment: Create any and alter any  database  can drop database  So,have any solution??

Comment: Alter any database Role permit to drop database

Comment: No,   i want the login  can creat any database, but can not drop database /   And  login  can  creat any login , but can not delete login

Comment: You should set permissions database by database,  and on each database deny drop.